# Conda package specifications in conflict with itself?

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, failed-installation, ggrepel

With:

```
conda install -c bioconda r-ggrepel
```

I get the error:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - r-ggrepel
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What does it mean when a package seems to be in conflict with itself?

Comment: I believe it's more about being in conflict with your current environment. When you run `conda info bioconda::r-ggrepel`, are any of the dependencies incompatible with your current package list (`conda list`)?  Maybe attempt to install some of the dependencies to see if you also fail to solve.  Do you have any pinned packages?

Comment: I think this has been moved to conda-forge. Try installing it from there. All the bioconda versions were built with R <= 3.3.2 (based on `conda info r-ggrepel | grep -B2 bioconda`)